# A Question child of another Question

Tags: support, questions, asking-questions

I create a Question on Stackoverflow:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26472594/spring-hibernate-maven-svn-sts-tomcat7-running-too-slow

But after this Question was solved by me, another question around the same issue appear. Should I create another Question or Answer inside this one?

An idea: If StackExchange have child questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each question should stand alone, but can reference previous questions.

Just ask a new question clearly explaining how it's different/is an extension of your previous one.