# First posts review of an answer that contains another question

Tags: discussion, review-queues, answers

I came across [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/16219245) during review and wasn't sure on the best action. I've skipped it for now. It does, sort of, answer the question at hand, but then it proceeds to go on and ask another question.

[image: Screenshot of deleted answer]

My first instinct is to remove the extra question asked in the answer, but I'm not 100% sure on the best course of action. The only thing I could find on the topic was [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/275091/a-question-child-of-another-question), but that seems to be more from the Question asker's side and not an answerer's side. Also, the question asked, I believe, isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow.

So, what is the best course of action in this case? Is there a precedent?

Comment: Probably just neutrally comment with some links to the help center; they clearly don't know how SO works and are treating it like a discussion forum. There is no helping that, they need to help themselves first by reading the house rules.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The poster has mistaken the page for a forum thread. The post **doesn't offer any solution at all**; it's just a re-hash of the question. It should be removed and the user re-directed to post a question, although I don't think there's any way to trigger deletion from the new posts queue.

The action I'd recommend would be commenting, directing the user to *ask* instead of *answering*, and -- if you feel so inclined -- downvoting so that 20kers can vote to delete.

In cases where you're not comfortable evaluating whether there is indeed a solution to the question contained in the answer, feel free to Skip the review.